# how to make the last row of an as3 advanced datagrid editable while all other rows are not editable

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

I'm trying to make a single row of a data grid editable. so if I have 5 rows of complete data these will remain uneditable. however I will have added an additional empty row and this is the only row I want the user to have access to edit. this is being done using as3 in and advanced data grid.
    using the editable property of the data grid I have made the entire grid editable but this will be an unacceptable outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify editable property of datagrid as true but specify all the colums of datagrid editable property false

On ItemClick event check the rowindex.

If rowindex == 5(where u want ur datagrid to be edited) use editable property of datagrid for all colums to true else false

Hope you got it!!!

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/665669